# MySQL: show only a record in left join when is present a value or another in right table

Tags: mysql

I had a table with these entries:

```
id  name                    id_language
1   San Paolo Stadium       2
1   Stadio San Paolo        1
1   Stade San Paolo         3
2   Castel Nuovo            1
2   Maschio Angioino        2
3   Abbazia di Sant'Antimo  1
4   Fontana di Trevi        1
4   Trevi Fountain          2
4   Trevi-Brunnen           3
```

First column belongs to a table called "Places", containing informations about a certain "place". Second and third column belong to another table called "Names", containing names of these places in various languages, identified by "id_language" value. These two tables are joined with a "one to many relationship", where one "Place" can have one ore more "names" in different languages.

I want to show with a query ONE AND ONLY of these names per place, with this criteria:
1) If exists a name of a place with a certain id_language given to the query, print ONLY that name;
2) Else, print the name of that place with another id_language.

Example: I want all the places having a name with id_language = 2. The places without a name with id_language = 2 will be printed with the name containing id_language = 1, like this:

```
id  name                    id_language
1   San Paolo Stadium       2
2   Maschio Angioino        2
3   Abbazia di Sant'Antimo  1
4   Trevi Fountain          2
```

---

Original query:

```
SELECT places.id,
       name_descriptions.name,
       name_descriptions.id_language
FROM places 
LEFT JOIN places_name_descriptions ON places.id = places_name_descriptions.id_places 
LEFT JOIN name_descriptions ON places_name_descriptions.id_name_description = name_descriptions.id 
ORDER BY places.id, name_descriptions.name ASC
```

Comment: and where is your query?

Comment: Ehr, I'm asking for it :D

Comment: but at least you should show what you have tried

Comment: Anyway, I show the original query to show the first table in this post:

`SELECT
  `places`.`id`,
  `name_descriptions`.`name`,
  name_descriptions.id_language
FROM `places`
  LEFT JOIN `places_name_descriptions` ON `places`.`id` = `places_name_descriptions`.`id_places`
  LEFT JOIN `name_descriptions` ON `places_name_descriptions`.`id_name_description` = `name_descriptions`.`id`
ORDER BY places.id, `name_descriptions`.`name` ASC`

Comment: @meda this is the problem, I had no idea of what I had to do. Making a Where clause with "or" and grouping by places id it will take names randomly.